# Input Validation - Style

Tags: jquery, validation, css, html5-canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/dm6Hm/23/
I would like to know if it's possible to validate the style of my input but this should only happen once I click onto the input field, meaning that background color returns to it's default white colour after I've finished typing and click somewhere else. So far it's able to receive data and validate the information correctly but it won't reset the white background if I click anywhere else.

```
<input type="email" class="Email" value="Email"/>
<input type="text" class="fname" value="First Name"/>

function isEmail(email){
    var reg = /^(\w)+(\.\w+)*@(\w)+((\.\w+)+)$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

$(".Email").keydown(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isEmail($test.val())) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
    }, 0);
    }else{
    setTimeout(function() {
        $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
    }, 0);
    }
});

function isfname(text){
    var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
    return reg.test(text);
}

$(".fname").keydown(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isEmail($test.val())) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
        }, 0);
     }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: why use setTimeout? Anyway you can try to reset background on `blur`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, could you please show me how to reset the background on blur (using my example) Tallmaris? I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment I don't see the reason to use `setTimeout` to highlight the background. You can do it directly. Also, you can then use `blur()` to reset the background.

This is the example for the email field, you can do the same for the First Name:

```
$(".Email").keyup(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this);
    if (isEmail($test.val())) {
        $test.css("background-color", "green");
    } else {
        $test.css("background-color", "red");
    }
}).blur(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");  
});
```

Here is the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dm6Hm/28/

Comment: Thanks for fixing that up, you're a true genius.

Comment: Silly syntax error: missed a bracket in the `if`. It happens when copy-pasting :) http://jsfiddle.net/dm6Hm/28/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one......   [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dm6Hm/29/)

```
function isEmail(email){
    var reg = /^(\w)+(\.\w+)*@(\w)+((\.\w+)+)$/;

    return reg.test(email);
}

$(".Email").keyup(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isEmail($test.val())) {
        setTimeout(function() {    
            $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
$(".Email").blur(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isEmail($test.val())) {
        setTimeout(function() {    alert("dsd");
            $test.css("background-color", "white").focus();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
function isfname(text){
    var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
    return reg.test(text);
}

$(".fname").keyup(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isfname($test.val())) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "green").focus();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});


$(".fname").blur(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if (isfname($test.val())) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "white").focus();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: it's fluttering, going red white red white.

Comment: yes but it's not staying, it goes white for one second and it goes back to red, I think you've almost got it.

Comment: i got it check demo link now

Comment: Thanks for the effort, nice try.